# Second order differential equation from physics

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, physics, curves

Trying to use Desmos to curve-fit some positional data of a ball bearing falling through water, and I want that curve to be relevant to $F_D=-kv^2$. So by mixing that with Newton's 2nd law, I got this equation:
$$
mg-k\left(\frac{dx}{dt}\right)^2=m\frac{d^2x}{dt^2}
$$
Where $m$, $g$, and $k$ are positive, non-zero constants, and for all $t\geq0$, $x(t)\geq0$, $x'(t)>0$

But I can't see how to solve the thing for $x$.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** Start by solving a simpler equation:$$m\frac{dv}{dt}=mg-kv^2$$
Then integrate to get $x$. Let me know if you still have problem with this.

**Edit:**
$$\frac{dv}{dt}=g\left(1-\frac k{mg}v^2\right)$$
Note that you can define the terminal velocity when the acceleration is zero, so $$v_T^2=\frac{mg}k$$
Then $$\int\frac{dv}{1-\frac{v^2}{v_T^2}}=g\int dt$$
Integrating, you get $$v_T\mathrm{arctanh}\frac{v}{v_T}=gt+C$$
From here, I would need the initial velocity to get $C$. Let's assume that $v(0)=0$. Then $C=0$ and $$v=v_T\tanh\frac{gt}{v_T}$$
Integrating $\tanh$ is easy (it's $\sinh$ divided by $\cosh$). Assuming $x(0)=0$, you get $$x(t)=\frac{v_T^2}g\ln\cosh\frac{gt}{v_T}$$

Comment: yeah, about that. Tried that first, and it got ugly FAST, like very big and many absolutes. Either I don't know what I'm doing or I need to know more about absolute functions.

Comment: @bet, that information should go in the original question. It helps people give better answers, and avoids wasting everyone's time giving you suggestions you've already tried.

Comment: mb, thanks boss

Comment: Note that you need to slightly modify the last part if you have some initial velocity.